# How to add a category to the results of a query?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT date, fruit, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM fruits
GROUP BY date, fruit
```

that gives the following results:

```
date           fruit      count
--------------------------------
2020-10-03     apple        3
2020-10-03     orange       5
2020-10-04     apple        23
2020-10-04     orange       1
2020-10-05     apple        10
2020-10-05     orange       6
```

Is it possible, and if so, how, to add a new fruit to the above results `mango` if it does not exist for every `date` with `count=0`, as shown below?

```
date           fruit      count
--------------------------------
2020-10-03     apple        3
2020-10-03     orange       5
2020-10-03     mango        0
2020-10-04     apple        23
2020-10-04     orange       1
2020-10-04     mango        0
2020-10-05     apple        10
2020-10-05     orange       6
2020-10-05     mango        0
```

Comment: You might want to ask a *new* question if you are concerned about fruits that exist on *some* but not *all* dates.

Comment: Yep, posted it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64246766/10798653. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT date, fruit, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM fruits
GROUP BY date, fruit
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT f.date, 'mango', 0
FROM fruits f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fruits WHERE date = f.date AND fruit = 'mango')
```