# How to add a category to the results of a query based on the output?

Tags: mysql, sql

Extending [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64244624/10798653) question for a more general case:

I have a table called `fruits` with a column `fruit` that has three possible values: `apple`, `orange`, and `mango`. I used  the following query to get the counts of each `fruit` by `date`:

```
SELECT date, fruit, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM fruits
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-10-02' AND '2020-10-05'
GROUP BY date, fruit
```

that gives the following results:

```
date           fruit      count
--------------------------------
2020-10-02     apple        3
2020-10-02     orange       5
2020-10-03     orange       23
2020-10-03     mango        1
2020-10-04     mango        9
2020-10-05     apple        10
2020-10-05     orange       7
2020-10-05     mango        6
```

As you can see, not every `date` contains each type of `fruit`.
Is it possible, and if so, how, to add the **missing** fruit by each `date` to the above results  with a default `count=0`, as shown below?

```
date           fruit      count
--------------------------------
2020-10-02     apple        3
2020-10-02     orange       5
2020-10-02     mango        0
2020-10-03     orange       23
2020-10-03     mango        1
2020-10-03     apple        0
2020-10-04     mango        9
2020-10-04     apple        0
2020-10-04     orange       0
2020-10-05     apple        10
2020-10-05     orange       7
2020-10-05     mango        6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` ot generate the row and then a `left join` to bring in the results:

```
select d.date, f.fruit, coalesce(ff.count, 0) as count
from (select distinct date from fruits) d cross join
     (select distinct fruit from fruits) f left join
     fruits ff
     on ff.date = d.date and ff.fruit = f.fruit;
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I may ask, in the situation of an edge case where one category does not exist in the table at all, in which case `select distinct fruit from fruits` will not contain all the possible values, how would the query change?

Comment: @Saurabh . . . You would add `union all` or use some other table that *does* have all the values you want.